# What is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^\alpha}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, closed-form

In Euler's *Introductio in Analysin Infinitorum* I found
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(3n+1)^3}-\frac{1}{(3n+2)^3}\right)=\frac{4\pi^3}{81\sqrt{3}}.$$
Instead of using Euler's approach, I thought that this sum could be tackled by writing
$$S=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n+1)^3}$$
and then using
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^3}=\pi^3\cot \pi z\operatorname{csc}^2\pi z.$$
However, this poses a problem for me because I actually don't know how to prove that $1/(z-n)^3$ identity. But I do know how to prove analogs of that identity with $1/(z-n)^2$ and $1/(z-n)$.

It led me to the following question:
Given that
$$\begin{align}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N\frac{1}{z-n}&=\pi \cot\pi z,\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}&=\pi^2\operatorname{csc}^2\pi z,\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^3}&=\pi^3\cot\pi z\operatorname{csc}^2\pi z,\end{align}$$
for all complex $z$ (except for a set of isolated points), does this pattern continue? I.e. can
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^\alpha}$$
be evaluated as a finite combination of trigonometric functions for every positive integer $\alpha$? If so, how can an *arbitrary* identity from this family be proved?

Comment: Start with $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N\frac{1}{z-n}=\pi \cot\pi z$ and differentiate both sides with respect to $z$ $(\alpha-1)$ times.

Comment: @Gonçalo How can we prove uniform convergence in order to be able to interchange the derivative and infinite series?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just being pragmatic as Euler. :-)

Comment: for $\sum 1/(z-n)^k, k \ge 2$ we trivially have normal convergence (absolute and uniform on compacts away from the integers (because $\sum_{n >0} 1/n^k < \infty$) while for $\sum 1/(z-n)$ where we need to use Cauchy (symmetric) summation it's better to think of it as $1/z+\sum_{n \ne 0} (1/(z-n)+1/n)$ which is normally convergent now due to the $1/n$ factor but that cancels out in the Cauchy summation so the symmetric partial sums are same

Comment: @Conrad We could as well start at differentiating $\sum 1/(z-n)^2$. Why does uniform convergence hold here? If I understand correctly, you say it's because $\sum 1/n^2\lt\infty$ but how can you get rid of the $z$ term?

Comment: normal convergence holds - so uniform and absolute but only on compacts away from the integers (trivially there is no uniform convergence on say the punctured disc of radius $1/2$ because of the singularity at $0$ etc); that of course is enough for term by term differentiation; and it holds because if $z \in K$ so $|z| \le M, |z-n| \ge c$ we can majorize the series by $\sum_{|n| \ge M+1} 1/||n|-M|^k$ plus finitely many terms with $|n| \le M$ that are uniformly continuous on $K$ and $\sum_{|n| \ge M+1}1 /||n|-M|^k$ converges as $k>2$